# How do I benchmark a web page, including all images, scripts, stylesheets etc

Tags: web, performance, benchmarking, pagespeed, apachebench

I've tried using a couple of tools (apache bench, html_load) but they only request a single file.

I'm testing out bundling strategies and so I need the tool to also download any stylesheets, scripts etc. included in the original html file. 
I.e. exactly what a browser would load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Google Chrome's Developer tools pretty useful for this kind of thing.